# MySQL: Select first member who doesn't belong to a gang, with one query?

Tags: mysql

I am trying to fetch just one record (row) from my `profiles` table that doesn't have a pivot record in `gang_entries` table.

`gang_entries` has two columns,

```
`profile_id` - the profile it refers to
`gang_id` - the gang the profile is entered into.
```

How can I select the first record, ascending by `id` of `profile` that doesn't belong to a gang, who doesn't have a record in `gang_entries`.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

You may try

```
SELECT p.* FROM profile p
LEFT JOIN gang_entries g
ON p.id = g.profile_id
WHERE g.gang_id IS NULL
ORDER BY p.id
LIMIT 1;
```